# Apache2 after update from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: apache2

I´m using a webserver (PHP) this works fine until 13.10. Now I updated to 14.04 TLS

The Apache2 server (my impression) not in the correct directory \var\www

This is what I see:

```
Index of /

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at luke2 Port 80
```

When i´m using a http://luke2.avmbenelux.local/info.php I see:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /info.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at luke2 Port 80
```

When I look into /var/www I see info.php available

apache2.conf:

```
# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I looked at the 000-default virtual host. It had the DocumentRoot as /var/www/html instead of /var/www. Once I change that, and restarted Apache, all was well with the world again.